# How to get media query breakpoint to work properly?

Tags: css, web, media-queries, responsive, breakpoints

I'm learning css positioning and I have a rotated image that goes behind another section on desktop size, but I want to make it take up the whole screen and straighten when the viewport becomes tablet size and mobile.

The problem is, at the breakpoint of 1020px, the photo only straightens but stays in the same line and just becomes smaller. It only takes up its own line when it reaches the mobile breakpoint.

How can I fix this?

This is the code I used to try and get this result:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1020px){

  .title-img{
    width: 60% !important; 
    position:static !important;
    transform: rotate(0) !important; 
  }
}
```

I want to note that I have included the    tag at the start of the document, so that isn't it.
Another note is that I am using the Bootstrap grid system for responsiveness, which could be the problem, but I haven't figured out how to fix it.

Comment: Can you post some images about how you want it and how you currently have it?

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1020px){

    .title-img-div, .title-text-div{
    width: 100%;
  }

  .title-img{
    width: 40% !important; 
    position:static !important;
    transform: rotate(0) !important; 
    margin-left: 0; 
  }

  #title{
    text-align: center;
  }

}
```

Wrapping the image and the text above it in a separate div and giving them another class apart from the bootstrap class, then targeting that class and changing the width to 100% fixed the problem.